# How to run a nested query depends on a condition

Tags: sql, hive

Is it possible to run queries depends on a condition? 
I mean,
i have a table with id, score, amt, time.
I have to group by id and has to get max score record for every id,
if two records with same id and score then i has to go for amt, if amts also same then to time.

It is possible to do this in a single query !!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible if you do a self join.  However, the fact that you have two records with the same id suggests that your db might not be normalized.  If any event, the general idea is this:

```
select case
when t1.id = t2.id and t1.score = t2.score then t1.amt
else t1.time end fieldalias
from yourtable t1 join yourtable t2 on something
where whatever
```

However, this will only work if amt and time are the same datatype.  Plus I have no idea what field to use to do your self join.